# Which row was chosen by the user

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How can I tell which row (doesn't really matter to me which text field exactly) was chosen in the JTable. I want to be able to edit a row that was chosen by the user.

I will appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a ListSelectionListener to the table's ListSelectionModel. It's quite easy to do. The ListSelectionEvent object passed into the valueChanged method can tell you the selected row(s). Or you could simply query the JTable via its getSelectedRow or getSelectedRows method.